# Inner where query in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I can't get this to work, maybe I still don't understand this clearly.

```
//get the Schools of the local government selected
        $churchs = Church::with(['confirmed' => function($q){ $q->where('status', 1);}])
                         ->where('state_id', request('state'))->get();
        return response()->json(['churchs' => $churchs]);
```

I have this relationship in place too

```
 public function confirmed() {
    return $this->hasOne(Confirmed::class, 'church_id', 'id');
}
```

This constraint `$q->where('status', 1)` does not take effect when I execute the above query. Although there no errors, but I get list of churches whose status is 0 too which is not suppose to be.

I need a simple explanation on how to go about this, thanks.

Comment: Attach tables schemas and relation 'confirmed' from Church model.

Comment: @IndianCoding done, thanks.

Comment: `status` is a column of churches or confirmed tables?

Comment: @IndianCoding of `confirmed` table

Comment: answered. Hope it will helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`with()` only eager loads relations. Condition statements inside `with()` only filters relations results, not of base model (table). You query looks like: Take all churches and load to them only confirmed with `status=1`.

To filter base table results by relation's column value you should use `whereHas()` or `whereDoesntHave()` methods.

```
$churchs = Church::whereHas('confirmed', function($query){
        $query->where('status', 1);
    })
    ->where('state_id', request('state'))
    ->get();
```